# Get const array from DLL using ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

How can I access a const float array from a DLL?  I am currently getting an int out of the DLL using:

```
DLL = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('some.dll')
x = ctypes.c_int.in_dll(DLL, 'x')
```

Is there a similar syntax to get out a float array?  Note I also know its size.  There is no existing function to return that array and I would prefer to not have to create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
ctypes.ARRAY(ctypes.c_float, array_length).in_dll(DLL, 'x')
```

Or with a prettier syntax:

```
(ctypes.c_float * array_length).in_dll(DLL, 'x')
```